# Both Client and Server Websocket connection in same script

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I've been attempting to get a python script that will simultaneously run as a websocket server for a web based client interface and connect as a client to an ESP32 board listening for commands.

What I have so far is little more than a non working and massively trimmed down version of the [Websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/) library example.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import asyncio
import itertools
import json
import websockets


async def Client_handler(ClientWebsocket):
    # Initialize a Connect Four game.

    async for message in ClientWebsocket:
        print(message)

        # Send data to the control board
        await ESPWebsocket.send('Message to Hardware')

        ClientUpdate = {
            "type": "Motion",
            "Direction": 1,
        }
        await ClientWebsocket.send(json.dumps(ClientUpdate))


async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(Client_handler, "", 8001) as ClientWebsocket, websockets.connect("ws://192.168.1.192/ws") as ESPWebsocket:
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I was hoping to be able to both update the hardware and send status updates back to the client browser, however I can't figure out a way to get access to both of them at the same time.

As soon as I connect the client I get:

```
    await ESPWebsocket.send('Message to Hardware')
NameError: name 'ESPWebsocket' is not defined
```

I can use the [websocket-client](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client) library and pass data with a webhook however I have no way to send live feedback to the client doing it this way.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import time
import webhook_listener
import websocket
import threading
import rel


######################################
# Global Vars
######################################
MagicNumber = 0
StopServer = False


######################################
# Setup defs
######################################
def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    global StopServer
    print("Opened connection")
    
    webhooks = webhook_listener.Listener(handlers={"POST": process_post_request})
    webhooks.start()
    
    while StopServer == False:
        # print("Still alive...")
        print(MagicNumber)
        print(time.time())


def process_post_request(request, *args, **kwargs):
    global MagicNumber, StopServer
    
    print(kwargs)
    if kwargs['StopServer']:
        StopServer = True
    
    MagicNumber = kwargs['Number']
    
    return



websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://192.168.1.192/ws",
on_open=on_open,
on_message=on_message,
on_error=on_error,
on_close=on_close)

ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel, reconnect=5)  # Set dispatcher to automatic reconnection, 5 second reconnect delay if connection closed unexpectedly
rel.signal(2, rel.abort)  # Keyboard Interrupt
rel.dispatch()
```

I've been searching for a couple of days trying to find an example from someone who has already managed it and found nothing that has helped.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: why do you use `ESPWebsocket` if you didn't create it and you didn't import it form some file?

Comment: the example from the documentation you posted shows how to send using `.send()` in `echo` and how to receive using `.recv()`. each socket exposes both `send` and `recv`, so you don't need to create two separate sockets for sending and receiving.

Comment: @OM222O I'm connecting to 2 separate endpoints the one on the ESP32 board that I didn't write that only understands a handful of Gcode like signals so I can't just use it to serve both and one for a web based client interface that I'm writing and while I can make it work with the webhook I'll have to do the calculations twice so that I can show movement on the client side as well as update the board. My major problem is I can't figure out how to send to the ESP websocket from the client handler.

Comment: @furas it was created on the first line of main() I just can't figure out how to access it from within the server's client handler function.

Comment: you would have to create in normal way `ESPWebsocket = websockets.connect(...)`. And it need also `global ESPWebsocket` (in function `main()`) to keep it as global variable. This way other functions can access `ESPWebsocket`